# ¿Cómo escribir etcétera después de abreviado?

Tags: gramática, ortografía

Etcétera se puede usar con abreviatura sin redundar con los puntos suspensivos, pero ¿cuál es la forma correcta de usar la abreviatura en el medio de un texto?

Ejemplo:

> ... los elementos del panel pueden mostrar imágenes, videos, gráficos interactivos, botones, etc. que brindarán una mejor experiencia de usuario ...

Estrictamente la letra inicial de una palabra precedida de un punto debe iniciar en mayúscula, pero ¿para el caso de «etc» también?

¿La abreviatura de «etcétera» siempre debe ser seguida por un punto (aunque no denote fin de la oración)?

Answer (score 7):

Si la palabra etcétera forma parte de una enumeración pero la frase continúa, no debe desaparecer la coma después de usar la abreviatura:

> “Es una persona fuerte, valiente, **etc.,** además de practicar baloncesto [...]”.

El punto señala la abreviación de la palabra, en ningún momento realiza otra función. Sin embargo, en el caso del punto final de frase no sucede lo mismo: el punto que acompaña a etc. se pone para indicar que se ha abreviado la palabra y con este punto se entiende también que la frase concluye, por lo que **sería incorrecto poner dos puntos 'etc..'**:

> “En esa tienda venden tartas, pasteles, bizcochos, **etc.** Los dependientes son muy amables [...]”.

Answer (score 3):

[Etc](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/etc%C3%A9tera)
(*Leer este enlace con cierto escepticismo. No se trata de un enlace a la RAE*)

Mira en la sección *Abreviatura etc.*

> *Siempre ha de llevar punto* salvo si le precede otro signo de puntuación.

El punto se emplea para cerrar la abreviatura, no como fin de sentencia. Y los puntos suspensivos no se emplean para elidir una repetición del *etc*, sino para prolongar una pausa entre la oración que justo acaba y la siguiente. Dando tiempo al lector para reflexionar sobre lo que se acaba de decir.

En el caso de tu oración:

> *los elementos del panel pueden mostrar imágenes, videos, gráficos interactivos, botones, etc. que brindarán una mejor experiencia de usuario*

Apostaría por una coma antes del *que* dando al lector una pausa después de una enumeración más o menos 'larga'

> los elementos del panel pueden mostrar imágenes, videos, gráficos interactivos, botones, etc., que brindarán una mejor experiencia de usuario

Lo que no estoy seguro, es si me arriesgaría con un punto y coma. No hay un cambio de idea tan drástico como para ello

Answer (score 2):

Si indica una abreviatura, no hay que poner mayúscula, pero si indica el comienzo de una oración, obviamente sí.

> *... botones, etc. que ...*
>   *... botones, etc. Estos brindarán ...*